# How to split a list into list of list by delimiter in Prolog

Tags: list, split, prolog, delimiter

I know this should be quite simple but I got no idea. Basically given a list such as `[a,b,c,' ',d,' ',e,f]`, the list should be split into list of list. In this example the output should be `[[a,b,c],[d],[e,f]]`

And currently I did something like this:

```
helper([], _, _).
helper([Elem|Rest], Sub, Result):- 
    (Elem == ',' -> 
        append(Result, Sub, NewResult),
        helper(Rest, [], NewResult)
    ;   
        append(Sub, [Elem], New),
        helper(Rest, New, Result)
    ).
```

Can anyone come up with some ideas?

Comment: Most declarative solution wins...

Answer (score 0):

Let's start by writing a `flatten/2` predicate which transforms a list-of-list into a flattened list, with the previous "list breaks" indicated by `~` (instead of `~`, but just because it's easier to look for in the source)

```
% flatten(ListOfLists,ListWithCommas)

flatten([Sublist1|[Sublist2|More]],MergedList) :-
   !, % not needed, but we want to tell Prolog to not 
      % look for more solutions in the next two clauses
      % because there aren't any
   append(Sublist1,[~],Part1),
   flatten([Sublist2|More],Part2),    
   append(Part1,Part2,MergedList).
flatten([Sublist],Sublist).
flatten([],[]).

% - - 8< - - - - - - - 8< - - - - - - - 8< - - - - - - - 
 
:- begin_tests(flatten).

test(a1) :- 
   flatten([],Result),
   assertion(Result == []).
   
test(a2) :- 
   flatten([[a,b,c]],Result),
   assertion(Result == [a,b,c]).

test(a3) :- 
   flatten([[]],Result),
   assertion(Result == []).

test(a4) :- 
   flatten([[a,b,c],[d,e,f]],Result),
   assertion(Result == [a,b,c,~,d,e,f]).

test(a5) :- 
   flatten([[a,b,c],[d,e,f],[g,h,i]],Result),
   assertion(Result == [a,b,c,~,d,e,f,~,g,h,i]).

test(a6) :- 
   flatten([[a,b,c],[],[g,h,i]],Result),
   assertion(Result == [a,b,c,~,~,g,h,i]).
   
:- end_tests(flatten).
```

This works fine. If we run the tests:

```
?- run_tests.
% PL-Unit: flatten ...... done
true.
```

We cannot magically "invert" the behaviour of the above (that would nice though):

```
?- flatten(ListOfLists,[a,b,c,~,d,e,f]).
ERROR: Stack limit (1.0Gb) exceeded
ERROR:   Stack sizes: local: 0.7Gb, global: 0.2Gb, trail: 60.4Mb
```

So we have to code a `heighten/2` we were are aware of the limitations of the built-in predicates and are aware of the data-flow:

```
heighten([],[]).  
heighten([Sublist],Sublist) :- 
   \+ member(~,Sublist),
   !.                                % Not needed, but tell Prolog to not look
                                     % for another solution via the next clause because there isn't one
heighten([Sublist1|[Sublist2|More]],MergedList) :-
   append(Part1,Part2,MergedList),   % Propose how to split MergedList into Part1 and Part2   
   append(Sublist1,[~],Part1),       % We demand that Part1 end with ~, which also gives us Sublist1
   \+ member(~,Sublist1),            % And ~ is itself not member of Sublist1
   !,                                % Not needed, but tell Prolog to not backtrack
                                     % past this point, because there are no more solutions there
   heighten([Sublist2|More],Part2).
   
% - - 8< - - - - - - - 8< - - - - - - - 8< - - - - - - - 
   
:- begin_tests(heighten).

test(b1) :- 
   bagof(Prior,heighten(Prior,[]),Bag),
   assertion(Bag == [ [] ,  [[]]] ). % clearly this mapping is not bijective
   
test(b2) :- 
   heighten(Prior,[a,b,c]),
   assertion(Prior == [[a,b,c]]).

test(b4) :- 
   heighten(Prior,[a,b,c,~,d,e,f]),
   assertion(Prior == [[a,b,c],[d,e,f]]).

test(b5) :- 
   heighten(Prior,[a,b,c,~,d,e,f,~,g,h,i]),
   assertion(Prior == [[a,b,c],[d,e,f],[g,h,i]]).

test(b6) :- 
   heighten(Prior,[a,b,c,~,~,g,h,i]),
   assertion(Prior == [[a,b,c],[],[g,h,i]]).
   
:- end_tests(heighten).
```

This is exactly what we need. I'm actually amazed that it works so well, I didn't completely trace the behaviour in my mind:

```
?- run_tests.
% PL-Unit: flatten ...... done
% PL-Unit: heighten ..... done
% All 11 tests passed
true.
```

It's not as efficient as a more imperative version as it "searches": `append(Part1,Part2,MergedList)` has to propose solutions until one matches.

Answer (score 0):

Splitting a list on delimiters shouldn't be any more difficult than this:

- remove items from the list until you encounter a delimiter, then
- recursively do the same on whatever was left over.

Something like this:

```
split( []    , _ , []       ) .  % if we find the end of the list, we're done.
split( [H|T] , D , [S|LoLs] ) :- % otherwise...
    take([H|T],D,S,R),           % remove items from the list until we find a delimiter
    split(R,D,LoLs).             % and recurse down on whatever is left.
```

`take/4` is about as trivial:

```
take( [H|T] , D , [H|S] , R ) :- H \== D , take(T,D,S,R). % non-empty list, no delimiter (yet).
take( [D|R] , D , []    , R ) .                           % non-empty list, delimiter found.
take( []    , _ , []    , []) .                           % empty list.
```